# Better solution for storing million images in folders?

Tags: php, linux, image, directory-structure

I am planing to store my pictures in folders according to their types and sizes:

images/{**OBJECT**}/{**OBJECT_ID**}/{**OBJECT_ID**}_{**SIZE**}.jpg

```
// FOLDERS LOOK LIKE THIS:
images/product/14/14_thumb.jpg
images/product/14/14_large.jpg
images/category/124/124_large.jpg
...
```

According to this approach, I can easily reach any object with a small effort:

```
function get_image($OBJECT, $OBJECT_ID, $SIZE){
    ...
}
// get image
get_image('product', 14, 'large');
```

I think it is good enough for me, but I want to be sure... Maybe I am missing something.

So what do you think?

Comment: Why do you need to repeat the object ID?

Comment: @BoltClock: yeah, you right :) I knew I was missing something.. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not good enough.
Explode ID to some count of parts, and each part will be the name of the directory level.
For example, ID 445578 you can store in
`/44/55/78/445578.jpg`
or
`/4/4/5/445578.jpg`
Size can be a suffix, yes.

You need to do it, because you can have more than 32k of IDs, but folder not always can keep more than 32k of files.

Comment: +1 Yes, at some level (number of images etc.) it can become really slow for PHP to support.

Comment: @OZ_: can i do this without folder_name as BoltClock just mentioned above? Like this: `images/product/445578_large.jpg`. Is it solve the problem you mentioned, right?

Comment: @dino beytar, Solution exactly in exploding ID to few names of directories (usually 2 or 3), read my answer one more time, sorry for my broken English :)

Comment: @OZ_: same here :). I just got the picture i think. thanks thought

Comment: @OZ_: by the way, can you make your second approach more clear? `/4/4/5/4455578.jpg`. What do you mean with `Size can be a suffix, yes`. Sorry for this, sometimes my brain doesn't work well.

Comment: @dino beytar, it's about your idea to add `_thumb` or `_large` as suffix about size. I just thinks it's not bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with this!

Answer (score 1):

there are several things wrong with this depending on what is really going on.

if these images free for public, then the only argument would be bandwidth that would get used when people form other sites link to images directly on your site.

if these images are not free and not public, there are big problems.  Whatever url naming you choose if it can be predicted after analysing a few urls, then the rest of the images can be directly accessed.

you should look at url rewriting in the scripting language that you are using.  and in your programming you should check for referer, authentication, authorization and quota.

The point being that the physical location of the images would be different from the location referred to by the url.